# how to rotate one object about another object's edge?

Tags: transforms

observe the image

[image]

the panel mesh are supposed to flip up along the red line but the line is not aligned to the grid. how does one change the orientation of the gizmo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to edit mode, select the edge and then add plus icon in transform orientation popover:

[image]

Then you can use it to rotate the panel:

[image]

If you want to use it in animation, you have to align the orientation of object to this custom orientation. To do this, enable transform only origin:

[image]

Then **Object** → **Transform** → **Align to Transform Orientation**

[image]

After this, disable transform only origin back.

If you do this correct, you will be able to rotate the object using local coordinates:

[image]